# OpenCV build with tesseract

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cmake, tesseract

I'm trying to build `opencv-4.5.1` with `tesseract-5.0.0` using `cmake` under `Windows 10`. First, I built tesseract with `C++17` (by default) as static lib. Then, when configuring `opencv`, cmake issues the message:

```
Tesseract:   YES (ver 5.0.0-alpha-20201231)
Can't use Tesseract (details: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/pull/2220)
```

Looking closely at the `opencv` flags I found that it was configured with `C++11`. Then I rebuilt `tesseract` with `C++11` support, but this error persists. As a result, `opencv` is built, but when creating an `OCRTesseract` object, a message is displayed that `tesseract was not found`.

Then I tried the older `tesseract-4.1.0` version. It is labeled LSTM. The error persisted.

What moment did I miss?

Comment: Did you cleared the CMake cache, i.e. deleted CMakeCache.txt, after rebuilding tesseract with C++11 support?

Comment: @vre Yes, of course